# Why are functions in an implicit class not available?

Tags: scala, scala-implicits

I am trying to teach myself Scala and am using IntelliJ IDEA as my IDE. I have launched IntelliJ's sbt shell, run `console` and then entered the following:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
import java.time.LocalDate
object DataFrameExtensions {
  implicit class DataFrameExtensions(df: DataFrame){
    def featuresGroup1(groupBy: Seq[String], asAt: LocalDate): DataFrame = {df}
    def featuresGroup2(groupBy: Seq[String], asAt: LocalDate): DataFrame = {df}
  }
}
import DataFrameExtensions._
val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]")).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
val df = Seq((8, "bat"),(64, "mouse"),(-27, "horse")).toDF("number", "word")
val groupBy = Seq("a","b")
val asAt = LocalDate.now()
val dataFrames = Seq(df.featuresGroup1(groupBy, asAt),df.featuresGroup2(groupBy, asAt))
```

It fails on the last line with:

```
scala> val dataFrames = Seq(df.featuresGroup1(groupBy, asAt),df.featuresGroup2(groupBy, asAt))
<console>:25: error: value featuresGroup1 is not a member of 
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
       val dataFrames = Seq(df.featuresGroup1(groupBy, asAt),df.featuresGroup2(groupBy, asAt))
                               ^
<console>:25: error: value featuresGroup2 is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
   val dataFrames = Seq(df.featuresGroup1(groupBy, asAt),df.featuresGroup2(groupBy, asAt))
                                                            ^
```

I've copied the code pretty much verbatim from elsewhere (where I know it works) so I don't know why this isn't working. Why are the functions defined in my implicit class not available as functions on a `DataFrame`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you need to rename the `implicit class DataFrameExtensions` to be a different name because there is an `object` with the same name. I guess the compiler got  confused to locate the `implicit class`  when you use

```
import DataFrameExtensions._
```

I rename it to below and it works now

```
 implicit class FeatureGroupImplicits(df: DataFrame){
    def featuresGroup1(groupBy: Seq[String], asAt: LocalDate): DataFrame = {df}
    def featuresGroup2(groupBy: Seq[String], asAt: LocalDate): DataFrame = {df}
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

*(Question edited, answer obsolete, might edit later)*

This here:

```
val groupBy = Seq('a','b')
```

produces `Seq[Char]`, not `Seq[String]`.. Since there is no method `featuresGroup1(s: Seq[Char], d: LocalDate)` on `DataFrame`, scalac will attempt to find an implicit conversion to a class that has this method. However, there is only

```
def featuresGroup1(groupBy: Seq[String], asAt: LocalDate): DataFrame
```

so `Seq[Char]` and `Seq[String]` don't fit together, and the compiler doesn't even report something like

> wrong parameter types for method `featuresGroup1`
>      expected: Seq[String]
>      received: Seq[Char]

because it doesn't see any connection with this method at all.

Use `Seq("a", "b")` instead.

Comment: thank you Andrey, unfortunately making your suggested change didn't solve the problem. I have edited my post anyway accordingly with your suggestion.